# Angular ngrx/store :Selector return null value

Tags: angular, redux, ngrx, ngrx-effects

As per title when I use my selector in my component I got undefined value. Here is my reducer

```
export interface State extends AppState.State {
transactions: TransactionState
 }
 export interface TransactionState {
  transactions: Transaction[]
  error: string
   }
   const initialState: TransactionState = {
    transactions: [],
    error: '',
      }

    export const transactionReducer = createReducer<TransactionState>(
     initialState,
     on(TransactionActions.loadTransactions, (state, action) => {
    return { ...state, transactions: action.transactions }
     }),
    on(
       TransactionActions.errorItem,
      (state, action): TransactionState => {
     return {
        ...state,
     error: action.message,
     }
    },
     )   ,
      )
    export const selectFeature = (state: State) => state.transactions
   export const selectTransactions = createSelector(
   selectFeature,
     (state: TransactionState) => state.transactions,
 )
```

Here my actions

```
export const getTransactions = createAction('[Transaction] get transactions')

 export const loadTransactions = createAction(
  '[Transaction] load transactions',
 props<{ transactions: Transaction[] }>(),
  )
```

And here my effect that make a call to backend service

```
@Injectable()
export class TransactionEffects {
constructor(
  private actions$: Actions,
  private transactionService: TransactionService,
   ) {}

loadTransactions$ = createEffect(() =>
 this.actions$.pipe(
  ofType(getTransactions),
  mergeMap((action) => {
    console.log('inside effect')

    return this.transactionService.getTransactionsByUsername(3).pipe(
      map((data) => {
        console.log('data', data)
        return loadTransactions({ transactions: data })
      }),
      catchError((error) =>
        of({
          type: '[Transaction] error item',
          message: error,
        }),
      ),
    )
  }),
),
```

)

When I dispactch the getTransactions action in my component adnd select the state I got the console log res undefined
[image]

```
 ngOnInit(): void {
this.userService.getBalance().subscribe((bal) => {
  this.currentBalance = bal
})
this.store.subscribe((state) => console.log('debug state store', { state }))
this.store.dispatch(TransactionActions.getTransactions())
this.store
  .select(selectTransactions)
  .subscribe((res) => console.log('res is', res))
```

Plus when I use the redux dev tool I got a transactionReducer object before my transactions object itself

[image]

Could someone explain me what is going on and what  am I missing? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Your first selector is already grabbing `transactions`

```js
export const selectFeature = (state: State) => state.transactions;

export const selectTransactions = createSelector(
  selectFeature,
  (state: TransactionState) => state // this one already has transactions
                                     // no need of state.transactions
);
```

So `undefined` is expected since `transactions.transactions` doesn't exit

Comment: Thanks. Now I have that res is something like {
    "transactionReducer": {
        "transactions": [],
        "error": ""
    }
} so i can have access to the transactions array by doing this res.transactionReducer.transactions but I had to put res as any type because I dont have  transactionReducer in my TransactionState is that correct?